# new WP_Query all post in a category inside the loop

Tags: categories, loop, list

Im trying to get a list of post in a category with this:

```
$category = get_the_category();

$args = array( 
    'post_type'           => array('post', 'entrevista'),
    'cat'                 => $category[0]->term_id,
    'post__not_in'        => array(get_the_ID()),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => -1
    );

$queryScience = new WP_Query( $args );

unset($args);
?>

<?php if ( $queryScience->have_posts() ) : while ( $queryScience->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_permalink($queryScience->post->ID); ?>"><?php echo ucwords(get_the_date('M Y', $queryScience->post->ID)); ?></option>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I think it goes infinity loop because shows more than 40.000 results. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) within your loop, otherwise you'll output the first post in an infinite loop, as `have_posts()` will always be true.

```
$queryScience->the_post();
```

Also, you don't need `wp_reset_query()` with `WP_Query`, `wp_reset_postdata()` is enough.